# How to catch multiple checkbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I want to make level permissions to create a new user.  I use ajax.  How can i capture the value in the checkbox in js?

Here is my code

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Hak Akses Register</label>
    <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($dlevel as $level) { ?>
       <div class="col-md">
          <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $level['id']; ?>" id="permission[]" />
          <label for="permission"><?php echo $level['nama']; ?></label>
       </div>
    <?php } ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var hak = $("#permission").val();
console.log(hak);
```

Comment: nice how to process to the database, I want to remove permissions [] I want data to record in databases like "1", "2", "3" etc

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
.prop("checked")
```

or

```
.attr("checked")
```

`.prop` evaluates the value as yes/no and `.attr` returns "checked" if checked, and should be blank if unchecked.  Hoever, if you want to target each one individually, using an ID="permission[]" won't get you that ability.  You would need a way to uniquely target each one so if the ID can be unique, that is the best way, or @Viney answer does a good job at an alternative using CSS, or using the value attribute.  Without understanding the context, it's hard to add more clarity.

As far as posting back to the server and processing there, make sure each checkbox has a name; name can be unique and you evaluate each one individually (note: checkboxes that are not checked do not post back to the server) and thus you could do it that way, or gave the same name to the checkbox, and it should give all of the responses in one long string value of the items checked...

See this online article for more information: http://net-informations.com/jq/iq/checked.htm

Comment: nice how to process to the database, I want to remove permissions [] I want data to record in databases like "1", "2", "3" etc

Answer (score 0):

Using `id` won't work as they must be unique and the array notation too won't work with ids you need to use `name` instead and that too in a dynamic way

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $level['id']; ?>" name="permission[<?php echo $level['id'];?>]" class="permission_cls" />
```

Give a class to all permission checkboxes like `permission_cls`

To get the checked items

```
<script> 

var permissions = [];

$('input.permission_cls:checked').each(function (i, item) {
    permissions.push( $(item).attr('name') );
});
 
</script>
```